# getting data using ajax php jquery

Tags: php, ajax

I made a submit form using php and ajax and don't get it why it doesn't work.

My code:

ex1.php

```
<form id="myForm">
<p> Firstname: <input type="text" name= "firstName"</p>
<p> Lastname<input type="text" name = "lastName" id="lastName"</p>
<p> Password: <input type="password" name= "password" id="myPass"> </p>
<p> Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="myEmail"></p>
<p> Age: <input type="text" name="age" id="myAge"> </p>

<input type="submit" value="submit" id="subm">
</form>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#subm").click(function(){

  var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
  var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
  var password = $("#myPass").val();
  var email = $("#myEmail").val();
  var age = $("#myAge").val();

   var dataString = "Firstname: " + firstName + ", Lastname: " + lastName + ", Email: " + email + " , Password: " + password + "Age: " + age;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ex1Ex.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            succes: function(result){
                alert(result);
            }
  });
    });
 });
```

externFile:

```
  <?php


$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
echo 'jsjsjs';

 ?>
```

When I enter the values, after pressing the button, in console it appears

```
ex1?firstName=a&lastName=ww&password=111&email=a&age=11:59 POST http://local.healix/ex1Ex.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The problem must be with the file ex1Ex.php, but I don't get it what.Any suggestions?

Comment: check if you can access the URL http://local.healix/ex1Ex.php directly in the browser.

Comment: yes, I can access it

Comment: ajax function success: function is misspelled.

Comment: As a side note, you do not need `cache: false` since your request is a `POST`. The `cache` parameter only applies to `GET` and `HEAD` requests (with one noted caveat explained in the docs). See the docs for [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your jquery function like following.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#subm").click(function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();    

        var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
        var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
        var password = $("#myPass").val();
        var email = $("#myEmail").val();
        var age = $("#myAge").val();

        var dataString = "Firstname: " + firstName + ", Lastname: " + lastName + ", Email: " + email + " , Password: " + password + "Age: " + age;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ex1Ex.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I think you have to prevent the default php form submission using [event.preventDefault();](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Also, please correct the spelling mistake; you have written **succes:**  instead of **success:**

Comment: The alert is good, but it doesn't put the values. there are no values

Comment: You only echoed `'jsjsjs'` do you see that?

Comment: As you mentioned in your question, on click of button it should show "jsjsjs" in alert.

Comment: yes, I edited in my file, but the values are not printed, only the "User ","Password" ..etc.

Comment: Please check whether you have written exactly same variable name while retrieving POST values in other file. php post array is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your data out in an object `.ajax` will deal with that nicely converting it into the `$_POST` array. You also dont need to go through interim declared variables, get the data right out of the DOM straight into the data property of the `.ajax` call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#subm").click(function(e){
        // stop the form submitting in the normal way as well as through AJAX
        e.preventDefault();  

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ex1Ex.php",
            data: {Firstname: $("#firstName").val(),
                   Lastname: $("#lastName").val(),
                   Email: $("#myEmail").val(),
                   Password: $("#myPass").val(),
                   Age: $("#myAge").val()
                  },
            //cache: false,
            success: function(result){   // spelling corrected
                alert(result);
            }
       });
    });
 });
```

Then remember that whatever the name you use for each parameter in the javascript is the name that will be used in the $_POST array so if you use `Firstname` in javascript you should expect a `$_POST['Firstname']` (case sensitive)

```
<?php
$firstName = $_POST['Firstname'];
$lastName = $_POST['Lastname'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$age = $_POST['Age'];
//echo "I received: $firstName, $lastName, $password, $email, $age";
// or better still while testing
echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: `cache: false` is not needed since it's a `POST` request.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with keys which you have used while posting in from ajax request eg. for first name its "Firstname" and you are accessing it with key 'firstName'

**php post array is case sensitive**